# Ending of Chrysalis

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, chrysalis

At the end of [Chrysalis (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0884335/), it turns out that the *real* daughter of Professor Brügen, Manon Brügen, lies on the bed in a coma at her mother's clinic. So who is the healthy girl? Is she another person who has had aesthetic surgery, or is she her twin sister?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [Coventry Telegraph - The Geek Files](http://blogs.coventrytelegraph.net/thegeekfiles/2008/05/chrysalis-movie-review-futuris.html) review of the movie, they state this:

> We learn that Brugen has created a duplicate of her dead daughter Manon using an abducted girl called Elena, whose face has been surgically changed to look like Manon and whose own memories have been removed and are being replaced with those of Manon. The crash-mangled body of Manon is being kept alive by Professor Brugen as a mere shell from which she is stripping her daughter's identity to put into Elena. Meanwhile, the memory transfer into Elena is slow and imperfect and she feels unease with her identity.

I do not know if this authoritative, but seems to me the "kicking" version of Manon is a duplicate.